# How to control the numeric type of value bound to scoped variable in XPages

Tags: java, xpages

**Background:**

I have a XPage with several controls that are all bound to viewScope variables.  Upon a button push event, I run call a java method that will update/insert into DB2 using JDBC (no Hibernate).

In my java method, I have a variable resolver which gets a handle directly to viewScope to access the data.  In the viewScope Map, all the data is stored as an Object, and then you have to cast to use the methods of the java.sql.PreparedStatement class.  I use this because parameters are added to the prepared statement instead of the SQL.  The SQL has question marks (?) where the dependency is added. (This is done for security - company policy).

Here is an simple example:

```
ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, (String) viewScope.get("firstName"));
```

The prepared statement has specific methods for each data type.  If the data type is wrong you get an exception.

**The Problem:**

On my XPage I have two numeric edit boxes.  They are identical, both use a numeric converter set to currency.  Both are set to integer only.  When I try to update one is stored as a Long, and one as an Integer.
Here is how I determined that:

```
System.out.println("NSA object type=" + viewScope.get("manageNSA").getClass().getName());
System.out.println("PNSAC object type=" + viewScope.get("managePNSAC").getClass().getName());
```

Log file result

```
02/02/2015 05:45:42 PM  HTTP JVM: NSA object type=java.lang.Long
02/02/2015 05:45:42 PM  HTTP JVM: PNSAC object type=java.lang.Integer
```

**Where is fails:**

```
ps.setInt(2, (Integer) viewScope.get("manageNSA"));
```

It also fails on the second one if I have this code.

```
ps.setLong(6, (Long) viewScope.get("managePNSAC"));
```

Exception traces:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long incompatible with java.lang.Integer
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.Long
```

**My Question:**

How in XPages can I force the numeric fields to always be a set as longs?? Or how can I force the type to whatever I want, double, long, int, etc ???

**What I tried:**

Casting both to a Long does not work, which makes no sense.  I know that I could have an `if` statement in my java that first checks the type, and then calls the appropriate method, but I would rather force XPages to set the type the same each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a Long value and set it to a scope variable with

```
viewScope.managePNSAC = java.lang.Long.valueOf(yourValue);
```

Comment: I tried doing this using this code:  var managePNSAC:String = @Text(viewScope.managePNSAC);
var manageNSA:String = @Text(viewScope.manageNSA);
viewScope.managePNSACLong = java.lang.Long.valueOf(managePNSAC);
viewScope.manageNSALong = java.lang.Long.valueOf(manageNSA); and it gives me this error:  java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.Long

Comment: Ignore this for now, please.

Comment: In case yourValue can be an Integer and not just String or Long then write `... = java.lang.Long.valueOf(yourValue.toString())`. This will work for all types. But I understood that you are looking for a way to always *create* a Long scope variable and for this code in answer should be fine.

Comment: I did exactly like above, and it just refuses to change the type. No matter what I do I am getting the same case exception. Giving up, and just going to write java to getClass.getName and run the correct method.

Comment: Already giving up ;-) ? You can check the type of scope variable with `print(viewScope.managePNSAC.getClass().getName())`. It shows me always "java.lang.Long"...

Comment: :) Sometimes you just have to move on. There are unrealistic deadlines awaiting.

Comment: Your fix does work, I was changing the INSERT method and trying to do an UPDATE...I was trying to code and pay attention to a CC at the same time.  Works perfect when I change the correct method. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to a double.  I THINK you need to go through that first.  Assuming that works then convert to Long or int from there.  I'm not sure... but my gut says you need to go through double when dealing with the xpages front end.

== edit

Another thing you could try is to set the var first...

var myVar:java.lang.Double = document1...  whatever

viewScope.put("myVar", myVar)

Something like that maybe...

Comment: I can't seem to find out how value gets set in XPages viewScope.  One time it gets set as Integer, one time as Long.  I will try it but I am 99% sure I will get the same cast exception.

Comment: Can't cast to Double:  java.lang.Long incompatible with java.lang.Double

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave.  I hoping someone knows how to force the Object type in the XPage.

Comment: see my additional comment above

Comment: Now your talking, I never thought about that.  Going to try it now.

Comment: @DavidLeedy I suppose binding will overwrite it.

Comment: I tried and couldn't make this work.  In my event, I tried to reassign the value and for some reason it didn't take.  

var convertToLong1:java.lang.Long = viewScope.get("managePNSAC");
viewScope.put("managePNSAC", convertToLong1);  Going to try using the Dojo Number Text Box next.

Answer (score 1):

Make helper class with `String get(String)` and `Long getLong(String)` methods with casts inside.

Your code will be:

```
Helper data = new Helper("viewScope");
ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, data.get("firstName"));
...
ps.setLong(6, data.getLong("managePNSAC"));
```

Constructor can use strig to identify binded map (can be `requestScope` or your own bean implementing Map interface).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To me, this seems like more trouble that asking the object what type it is in the if statement.  I am holding out for a solution where I can set it from XPages.

Comment: I think you are asking for too much. Helper approach will keep your code consistent.

Comment: I am not saying this isn't a good approach, I just was hoping for a XPages solution because I have many UPDATES/INSERTS to perform, and want to minimize helper classes. I would have to have several extra classes one for each.

Comment: Not at all: one helper class for any binding - it handles all your bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Try Dojo Number Text Box. It allows you to define the number type it's stored as using javaType.

Comment: Good suggestion, will go here if I can't make Knut's fix work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic converter tag and specify the converterId you want to use:

```
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
</xp:this.converter>

<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:converter converterId="javax.faces.Long" />
</xp:this.converter>

<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:converter converterId="javax.faces.Double" />
</xp:this.converter>
```

etc...

DDE doesn't do anything to help the discoverability of things that are built-in and come with the JSF environment XPages inherits from.